# How to extend a div to fill the whole template page(PDF) In NetSuite?

Tags: html, css, layout, freemarker, html-heading

There are one header and one footer in a FreeMarker template page.

I want to insert a div between the header and the footer.

And the div must extend to the footer.

The code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
    <head>
        <macrolist>
             <macro id="nlheader">
                 <table style="width: 100%; font-size: 10pt; position:fixed">
             </macro>
             <macro id="nlfooter">
                <table class="footer" style="width: 100% ;position:fixed">
             </macro>
        </macrolist>
    </head>
    <body header="nlheader" header-height="10%" footer="nlfooter" footer-height="65pt" padding="0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in" size="Letter">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Here is a table</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <div id="extend_div"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</pdf>
```

The height of HTML tag seems invalid in FreeMarker templates.

And I want to use JavaScript to detect the height of tables, but it seems also invalid.

How to configure the div to make it extend to the footer?

Comment: You should be use this simple trick: `#extend_div{height: 100vh;}`

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/u7reck5L/9/. You could see the purple background covering the whole space, Use flex property.

```
<div class="starter">
    <header>
      This is Hweader
    </header>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
          <h1>
           This is content 
          </h1>
    </div>
    <footer>
          This is footer
     </footer>
    </div>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    header, footer {
      height:30px;
    }
    .starter {
        display: flex;
        height: calc(100% - 30px);
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .main-wrapper {
        background-color: #8723FF;
        position: relative;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: It seems not support CSS3.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say, flex and calc both are CSS3. You can't use CSS3, is this what your concern is?

Comment: Yes, the system 'NetSuite' seems not suport CSS3, in other words, CSS3 seems not take effect on it.